# Disable Tab functionality on a GtkStackSidebar widget

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm creating a desktop application written in c, using Gtk3. In my application, I've got a couple different GtkStack children, and there's a GtkStackSidebar to switch between them. I've noticed that by default, the "tab" key can be pressed to toggle between the various stack children, and I would like to disable this, so that the user can only go from one stack to another by clicking. Does that make sense? I have been trying for some time to figure this out, and have been searching stackoverflow and have not found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved it. There appears to be a bug in Glade. In Glade, in the "common" tab for the GtkStackSidebar, the "can focus" open was unchecked. But I guess that was actually setting it to "true." When I checked the "can focus", it set it to false, and now the tab doesn't seem to select the sidebar tabs at all, which is exactly what I want.